# Array/Object Sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

So there's a JSON Object, it has a list of arrays with objects in it, like AssortmentID and AssortmentParentID with a Name, AssortimentID's with an AssortmentParentID of 000-000-000 are folders, the AssortmentID's with the AssortmentParentID of another AssortmentID are the children of that folder.
How do I output the folders first, and then the children in each folder(parent).
Example:

```
The HTTP Request:
const url = "\url";
async function getAssortList() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = response.json();
  const { Assortments } = data;

for (let i = 0; i < Assortments.length; i++) {
  const assortItem = Assortments[i];
  ...(where I'm stuck)...

/////////////////////////////////////

The JSON Response:
Assortments: [
{ 
  "AssortmentID": 123-123-123-123,
  "AssortmentParentID": 000-000-000
  "Name": "I am a parent"
},
{
  "AssortmentID": 111-111-111-111,
  "AssortmentParentID": 123-123-123-123,
  "Name": "I am a kid"
}
```

Comment: 1. This isn't about JSON or GET requests, at all. What you have there is an Array of Objects. That is used to be JSON and was loaded from the server is completely irrelevant. 2. You should use proper syntax, i.e. quotes around value strings. 3. Clarify the desired output. Do you want to add a `children` field to each Object that contains the children as array? 4. Please don't tag-spam.

Comment: First of all, I want to output only the Objects that are Parents, then access its children after clicking them.

Comment: Did you look at available Array functions yet? Like `.filter()` and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Comment: Yeah, I wonder how to use them in my case...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.

```
Assortments.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let parent = curr["AssortmentParentID"];
    if(acc[parent]){
        acc[parent].push(curr)
    }
    else{
        acc[parent] = [curr]
    }
return acc;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code in javascript

```
Assortments.sort(
  function (a, b) {  
    var x = a.AssortmentParentID.toLowerCase();
    var y = b.AssortmentParentID.toLowerCase();
    if (x < y) {return -1;}
    if (x > y) {return 1;}
    return 0;
})
```

by this you will have sorted array on `AssortmentParentID`

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, solved it myself. Still have things to do.

```
const parents = []; // created a new array that I'll push objects into later.
for (let i = 0; i < Assortments.length; i++) {
  if (Assortments[i].AssortimentParentID == "000-000-000") {
    parents.push(Assortments[i]);
  }
}
for (let i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
  parents.sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name)); // sort them alphabetically
}
```

If someone can show me how to do the same thing, using filter/find/etc., it would be great. Thank you!

UPDATE:
Managed to sort the parents, output them in DOM, here's the code:

```
for (let x in parents) {
  parents[x].isFolder === false ? parents.push( parents.splice(x,1)[0] ) : 0;
}
let assortItem = parents[i].Name;
let subnavList = document.createElement("li");
let subnavLink = document.createElement("a");
subnavList.classList.add("subnav-list");
subnavList.appendChild(subnavLink);
subnavLink.classList.add("subnav-link");
subnavLink.innerHTML += assortItem;
item.appendChild(subnavList);
```